# Consume messages that not loaded in memory with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, queue, jms, activemq-classic, message

I am trying to get working the next scenario:

I send multiple messages to activeMQ queue setting property on each message

```
message.setJMSCorrelationID(job.getUuid());
```

Form other side message consumer getting this messages and process it. That's working well.
Sometime I need to cancel particular messages in queue, to get this I am creating new consumer with selector

```
session.createConsumer(destination, "JMSCorrelationID='" + job.getUuid() + "'");
```

This consumer dequeues messages from queue by selector. This also works well but only when number of messages loaded in memory less that **maxPageSize** value in actimeMQ configuration.

Suppose I have **maxPageSize**=1000 in config, I am sending 1000 messages and not consume it, then I send 20 messages and want consume this 20 by selector but receive method stuck and hung. I suppose it doesn't see message because it persisted in database but not loaded in memory.

How I can get this working and how to consume messages by selector that not loaded in memory. Of course I can increase **maxPageSize** value, but this is last option I want apply. There are any other mq systems that covers this requirements?